# ¿Cómo le doy formato de millones con decimales a un número en Java?

Tags: java

Realice un método para obtener el promedio del costo de unos vehículos, pero el resultado me lo está retornando en notación científica.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que lo retorne en millones con decimales?

```
public double promedioPreciosVehiculos() {
    double promedio = 0.0;
    for (Vehiculo v : vehiculos){
        promedio += v.darPrecio()/vehiculos.length;
    }

    return promedio;
}
```

Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: ¿Formato monetario?

Comment: Sí, formato monetario.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase `NumberFormat`. En este caso usare el `Locale` de Estados Unidos. Pero puedes investigar algún otro si lo necesitas.

```
public String promedioPreciosVehiculos() {
    double promedio = 0.0;
    for (Vehiculo v : vehiculos)
        promedio += v.darPrecio() / vehiculos.length;

    NumberFormat formato = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    
    return formato.format(promedio);
}
```

El método `format` regresa un `String`, por lo tanto puedes seguir calculando el promedio en tu método `promedioPreciosVehiculos` y aplicarle el formato en donde sea que se llame a `promedioPreciosVehiculos`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es ambigua.
Según el título de tu pregunta, formato monetario pareciera que estas preguntando como agregar simbolos de dolar, euro, libra, etc.
Según el cuerpo de tu pregunta, estas preguntando como separar los millares con `,`
Responderé según el cuerpo de tu pregunta porque ya te respondieron según el título de tu pregunta.
Haremos uso de las clases `DecimalFormatSymbols` y `DecimalFormat`

```
public String promedioPreciosVehiculos() {
    double promedio = 0.0;
    for (Vehiculo v : vehiculos)
        promedio += v.darPrecio() / vehiculos.length;

    DecimalFormatSymbols simbolo = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        
    simbolo.setDecimalSeparator('.');  //separa los decimales con punto
    simbolo.setGroupingSeparator(','); //separa los millares con coma
    DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##",simbolo); //Formato que tendra nuestro número, ejemplo: 123,456,789.96 
        
    return formateador.format(promedio);
}
```